# unable to import cucumber options

Tags: selenium, maven-plugin, cucumber-java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGGCb.png)
error which is unable to import cucumberOptions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jt3N.png)
dependencies added for cucumber

Answer (score 0):

We just need to remove the " ##### " part from the dependencies that we add in pom.xml file.

Comment: What is wrong with the `<scope>` tag?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).